# GroupBy() overwrite my select statement Eloquent Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have this problem in this query, [sede for location and aule for classrooms]

```
$sedi = Sede::with('location', 'aule', 'tipologia_sedi')->join('static_sedi_tipologia', 'static_sedi_tipologia.id', '=', 'sedi.static_sedi_tipologia_id')
        ->leftJoin('aule', 'sedi.id', '=', 'aule.sedi_id')
        ->selectRaw("COUNT(aule.id) as n_aule, sedi.*, static_sedi_tipologia.nome as tipologia")->addSelect($count)
        ->groupBy('sedi');
```

in addition to having the data with the relationships in the collection that I take in need to get further data.
In this case I need to have the quantity of classrooms associated to one location for each location.
i notice in one of many try that the groupBy statement overwrite my select statement in

```
COUNT(*) as aggregate
```

i've tried groupByRaw(). Same problem.

In sql the query works fine

```
select COUNT(aule.id) as n_aule, sedi.*, static_sedi_tipologia.nome as tipologia
 from `sedi`
 inner join `static_sedi_tipologia`
 on `static_sedi_tipologia`.`id` = `sedi`.`static_sedi_tipologia_id`
 left join `aule`
 on sedi.id = `aule`.`sedi_id`
 GROUP by sedi.id
```

Comment: I think you forgot to use same as your query `->groupBy('sedi.id')`

Comment: @ApurvBhavsar already tried it. 
Same error

Comment: Have you tried without adding `addSelect()`.

Comment: yes that addSelect si a typo i forget to delete it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel Eloquent Relationship Features.

You can create Relation with **aule, sedi, tipologia_sedi, static_sedi_tipologia**.

For get count of `aule`

```
Use $query->withCount('aule')
```

This function returns the collection count associated with your foreign key.
You can access like `$variable->aule_count`